# How to create C# MVC model XML element with attribute and value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a c# MVC model which I would like to serialize to an XML document to look like this:

```
<Vehicle>
    <Type color="red" speed="50mph">Ford</Type>
    <Type color="blue" speed="70mph">Toyota</Type>
</Vehicle>
```

Here is the model:

```
[Serializable]
public class Production
{
    public List<Vehicle> Vehicles { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Vehicle
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string color { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string speed { get; set; }
}
```

Since class Vehicle is not a property what do I need to add to the class to give it a value of for example "ford" or "Toyota"

Right now I have:

```
var myvehicle = new Vehicle {color = "red", speed = "50mph"};
```

Comment: From the code you have, you are not storing the make anywhere...where does the data come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another property with the `[XmlText]` attribute:

```
[XmlText]
public string Make {get; set;}
```

You should also add attributes to your list of `Vehicles`:

```
[XmlArray("Vehicle")]
[XmlArrayItem("Type")]
public List<Vehicle> Vehicles { get; set; }
```